# How to validate the Checkbox if not ticket

Tags: sharepoint-server, nintex

I have an `Agreement` checkbox which is set to `NO` by default.
I like the checkbox to be validated when the form is submitted:

> IF Agreement is Empty/No 
>  Display: Read and agree to the Terms &
>   Condition

**What I have tried:**

[image]
I also tried via the `RULES`

[image]

I am lost of ideas...

This is the form for the user to fill out: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this via `default column validation` rather than nintex validation by doing the following :

- Go to list settings > Validation settings
- Add this formula

  `=IF(Choice="No",FALSE,IF(Choice="",FALSE,TRUE))`
- Try to test now , It should be working properly

[image]

**[Update]**

For nintex at condition section at this

```
choicefield  == "" || choicefield  == "No"
```

If not working Try adding two rule , one for **No** value and for epmty,

[image]

Comment: selam @M.Qasas, your suggestion may work when using the default form of Nintex, but I have created my own form, see above in my first post.  Any ideas ... ?

Comment: Hi @Bucki check the updated answer :)

Comment: yesss it worked :) I cant believe how many times I been trying with == 0 and did not work lol <br/>  `choiceBox == ""`  did the trick - thank you